# Entity Framework - how do I add a table back after hitting "Remove From Diagram"

Tags: entity-framework

on the model.edmx diagram, I meant to delete a table, but instead clicked the "Remove From Diagram" option.  This simply took the table off of the diagram but every time I save or compile it regenerates the underlying class file.

I thought I could add it back in and then delete it properly, but when I try to re-add the table via "Update Model from Database..." it does not appear in the list of tables able to add.

How do I re-add a table I "Remove From Diagram"-ed back onto the model?

Answer (score 9):

When you have the edmx open on the right hand side of VS there is a `Model Browser` tab [image]

When you click that tab you see sub-items

- `Diagrams`
- `Model`
- `Model.Store`

Click on `Model.Store` then `Tables/Views` and then right click the table you want to delete and click `Delete From Model`

Here's an example picture

[image]

Now you should be able to update your model again.

Comment: Thanks ... that's what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Open Model in Visual Studio.

Right Click in Model Page and click on "Mapping Details".

Click on "Model Browser".

In "YourDataBaseName Model" , in "Entity Types" find your lost table and drag it in your model page.

Save your model.